# Most efficient way to add a new object to a list property in ef core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-performance

I have the following code that I want to optimise for performance:

```
await using var context = await _contextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
var process = context.Processes
      .Include(p => p.Events)
      .First(p => p.Id == processId);
        
var eventRecord = _eventRecordFactory.CreateRecord(processEvent);
process.Events.Add(eventRecord);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This seams to be inefficient as I am loading the full process from the database as well as all existing events of the process.

I know that I can update properties without loading the full process from the database with `ExecuteUpdateAsync()`, but this seems not to help as I can only set a property. I don't want to set the List, because I don't want to lose previous events.

The attach method seems to be promising. I got following code with it:

```
await using var context = await _contextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
    
var process = new Process { Id = processId };
context.Processes.Attach(process);
    
var eventRecord = _eventRecordFactory.CreateRecord(processEvent);
process.Events.Add(eventRecord);
    
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

However I guess this will overwrite the List of events, so the List will only contain the last saved event. Is this correct?

Comment: What is relation between `Process` and `Event`? One-to-many?

Comment: Yes, one process can have many events and each event has only one process.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have corresponding setup (i.e. `Events` `DbSet` is exposed and `Event` has `Process` navigation) you can simply do:

```cs
await using var context = await _contextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
// assuming _eventRecordFactory.CreateRecord is not working with context, otherwise everything can be moved there    
var eventRecord = _eventRecordFactory.CreateRecord(processEvent);
var process = new Process { Id = processId };
context.Processes.Attach(process);
eventRecord.Process = process;
context.Events.Add(eventRecord);     
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

If `Event` has explicit declaration for `ProcessId` then even attach is not needed:

```cs
await using var context = await _contextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();  
var eventRecord = _eventRecordFactory.CreateRecord(processEvent);
eventRecord.ProcessId = processId ;
context.Events.Add(eventRecord);     
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```